# NodeJS sqlite3 concurrent access

Tags: node.js, sqlite, parallel-processing

Basically I have a database where not many accesses appear but sadly grouped by two.

Firstly, there is a write access to the database
Secondly, there is a read access.

The read access fails with the message that the database is locked (`{ [Error: SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked] errno: 5, code: 'SQLITE_BUSY' }`) which is totally normal. But how can I make my read access to wait until the database is closed?

My current code:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO chickenmilk (userID,channelID,message) VALUES (?,?,?)"
db.run(sql, userID, channelID, bot.fixMessage(message), function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    db.close();
});
```

And concurrent:

```
var sql = "SELECT userID, COUNT(message) as count FROM chickenmilk WHERE channelID LIKE ? GROUP BY userID";
db.all(sql, data, function(err,res) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return "";
    }

    callback(res); // data is used here
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: If NodeJS has an interface to [`sqlite3_busy_timeout`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html), you can use that. You can also use [WAL mode](http://sqlite.org/wal.html) to enable concurrent reads and writes.

Comment: Sorry for that dump question but can you give me an example how to use it? (so it retrys to do both read/write once a second) thanks :)

Comment: @Schwertspize when you use npm `sqlite3` you can enable WAL mode by this: `db.run("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL")`